# In RegEx, require at least one a-z character, but optional other characters

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to work out how to write some RegEx that **requires** *at least* one `a-z` character, but it can also optionally contain `0-9_-` characters as well.

I started out with the below initially when all characters were optional, as long as it contained at least one of them:

```
add_rewrite_rule('for-sale\/([a-z0-9_-]+)\/?$', 'index.php?pagename=for-sale&search_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

But then I needed to change it so that it is a requirement that *at least* **one** `a-z` be present, but the other characters are optional.

I tried the below, but unfortunately this obviously only works if these other characters are *after* the `a-z` characters:

```
add_rewrite_rule('for-sale\/([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)\/?$', 'index.php?pagename=for-sale&search_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

I need these optional characters to be able to be prepend, append OR even be *between* `a-z` characters; easy enough how to allow them to be in front, but not sure how to allow them in-between.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Replace `([a-z0-9_-]+)` with `([0-9_-]*[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple ha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `([a-z0-9_-]+)` with `([0-9_-]*[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)` and use

```js
add_rewrite_rule('for-sale\/([0-9_-]*[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)\/?$', 'index.php?pagename=for-sale&search_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

The `[0-9_-]*[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*` matches zero or more digits, underscores or hyphens first, then matches a lowercase ASCII letter (thus, requiring at least one occurrence) and then zero or more digits, lowercase ASCII letter, underscores or hyphens.